# Google Sheets Script for Printing Specific ranges of a worksheet w/ multiple tabs identical in layout

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, printing, helper

i'm hoping someone on here can help me with my problem. I am looking for a way to print only a certain range of cells (E5:S48) on a Google sheets file that has multiple tabs, all identical in layout, difference being information referenced. Is there a Script that someone can help me with?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide your current script and the current issue of your script, and also, provide the sample input and output situations as the image?

Comment: i dont have a script, ive been looking for one to try to modify to my needs.  i essentially want to print the range (E5:S48) for EVERY tab on the file

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to keep all the styles, display formats and layout would be:

1. copy the original spreadsheet ([`copy`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#copyname))
2. delete all rows ([`deleteRows`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowsrowposition,-howmany)) and columns ([`deleteColumns`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deletecolumnscolumnposition,-howmany)) you do not need.

---

If you want to refer to the values dynamically, further:

3. clear the content ([`clearContent`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent))
4. change the values into `IMPORTRANGE` ([`setFormula`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)).